# Why this variable is not being recognized here

Tags: loops, variables, julia

I am trying to learn Julia. Why is following simple code not running:

```
chnum = 3
while chnum < 100
    println(chnum)
    chnum = chnum + 2
end
```

The error is:

```
RROR: LoadError: UndefVarError: chnum not defined        <<<<< NOTE THIS.
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at /home/iuser/testing.jl:4 [inlined]
 [2] top-level scope at ./none:0
 [3] include at ./boot.jl:317 [inlined]
 [4] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1044
 [5] include(::Module, ::String) at ./sysimg.jl:29
 [6] exec_options(::Base.JLOptions) at ./client.jl:266
 [7] _start() at ./client.jl:425
in expression starting at /home/iuser/testing.jl:3
```

Why is `chnum` variable not being recognized here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of how scoping works in Julia. The documentation has a very good page on the [Scope of Variables](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/variables-and-scoping/), particularly relevant is the section [On Soft Scope](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/variables-and-scoping/#On-Soft-Scope) that explains the rationale behind why the rules are the way they are and also provides a bit of history (the behavior has changed a bit over time, in Julia 1.5 your code works in a REPL or a notebook).

In this case, the statement:

```
chnum = 3
```

declares a global variable named `chnum`. When the `while` loop starts a new local (soft) scope is created, since there is no local variable named `chnum` it is not defined.

The error can be prevented by declaring `chnum` `global`:

```
chnum = 3
while chnum < 100
    global chnum
    println(chnum)
    chnum = chnum + 2
end
```

or by wrapping the whole thing in a construct that introduces a local scope:

```
function print_stuff()
    chnum = 3
    while chnum < 100
        println(chnum)
        chnum = chnum + 2
    end
end
print_stuff()
```

Comment: Interesting that variables used in `while` loop are also local! Does this occur in any other language?

Comment: Yes and no. Lot's of languages have [Block scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#Block_scope) meaning that the variables declared in a block like `while` are only available inside that block and some of these languages allow shadowing inside a block, i.e. a block-local variable "hides" a variable outside of the block with the same name. However, Julia's particular scoping rules seem quite unique.

Comment: Just to add that the performance of the first version (with global chnum) will be bad because a global variable is not type-stable. The 2nd version (wrapping in function) should be preferred.